# Unable to redirect variable's value to file using ansible copy module

Tags: ansible, copy, echo, io-redirection, slurp

I have taken just a sample from a huge data that I wish to read from variables and dump in the file.

```
cat junk.txt

{:,:"(s):"}}
```

This data in the junk is not in my control and comes as output from a database script execution.

Below is my attempt to dump the data from junk.txt to a log file github.out and the junk data should keep getting appended to the github.out throughout my play which is something I m not able to achieve.

```
---

- name: "Play 1-Find the details here"

  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

   - name: Read junk file
     raw: "cat {{ playbook_dir }}/junk.txt"
     register: junkdata

#   - name: Dump data to file
#     raw: echo "{{ junkdata.stdout }}" >> "{{ playbook_dir }}/outputjunk.txt"

   - name: Direct script execution in Standard logs for GitHub actions (TXTstdout)
     ansible.builtin.copy:
       content: ">> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT1- {{ junkdata.stdout }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/github.out"
       force: no

   - name: Direct script execution in Standard logs for GitHub actions (TXTstdout)
     ansible.builtin.copy:
       content: ">> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT2- {{ junkdata.stdout }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/github.out"
       force: no
```

The commented section if uncommented to redirected content to log file gives me the below error:

> TASK [Dump data to file]
>
> ---
>
> Monday 27 November 2023  10:21:22 -0600 (0:00:00.035)
> 0:00:00.087 *******
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero
> return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error
> near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0:` echo
> "{:,:"(s):"}}'\n", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax
> error near unexpected token `('", "/bin/sh: -c: line 0:` echo
> "{:,:"(s):"}}'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

I therefore decided to use the `copy` module to dump the data to a file which it does.

But I wanted each content to keep appending to github.out which it does not.

Expected / Desired output:

```
$ cat github.out
>> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT1- {:,:"(s):"}}

>> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT2- {:,:"(s):"}}
```

Current output:

```
$ cat github.out

>> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT1- {:,:"(s):"}}
```

And if the github.out exists from the previous run then nothing gets appended.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote raw module like below to fix the first error:

```
raw: "echo {{ junkdata.stdout }} >> {{ playbook_dir }}/outputjunk.txt"
```

`copy` module overwrites the content. So use `lineinfile` instead, with a loop
like:

```
   - name: Direct script execution in Standard logs for GitHub actions (TXTstdout)
     loop:
         - ">> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT1- {{ junkdata.stdout }}"
         - ">> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT2- {{ junkdata.stdout }}"
     ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
       path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/github.out"
       create: true
       line: "{{ item }}"
```

```
$ cat github.out
>> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT1- {:,:"(s):"}}

>> TXT SUCCESS OUTPUT2- {:,:"(s):"}}
```

Comment: the issue is that when i read from the file and display all identation is lost and I see so many backward slashes and new line characters are also lost ... sample data as displayed: `\\"9true{\\"db\\":\\"WDA-US-DEV\\",\\"collections\\":50,\\"views\\":0,\\"objects\\":48452261,\\"avgObjSize\\":2144.542052805338,\\"dataSize\\":103907911268,\\"storageSize\\":26887352320,\\"indexes\\":120,\\"indexSize\\":2851209216,\\"totalSize\\":29738561536,\\"scaleFactor\\":1,\\`. Can I dump to the file while preserving the formatting identations ?

Comment: The reason is the ```raw``` module which should only be used in a few cases like installing python. Use ```command``` or ```shell``` module instead.

Comment: I m using `lineinfile` to dump data and `slurp` to read and display ... i will open a new thread to help with formatting.